# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, fragment-tab-host

In my `HomeFragment` i added two tab using Tabhost.Two fragment are there in tabhost.From `Tabhost fragment 1` i have to go to the another Fragment.But it gives error as `No view found`.I unable to understand this issue please help me to resolved this.

Below code is my `tabhost fragment 1`.From this Fragment I have to go the another fragment.

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment
{

    String strtext;
       View FaramentView;

    TextView home_item_price;
    TextView home_item_name;
    ImageView home_item_image;
    String itemDescription;
    String itemName;
    String ItemPath;
    String ItemCode;
    double itemPrice;


    Button home_button_shop_now;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, null);
        //TextView.class.cast(rootView.findViewById(R.id.labelText)).setText("Earth");

        home_item_name=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_name);
        home_item_price=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_price);
        home_item_image=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_image);
        home_button_shop_now=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_button_shop_now);

        home_button_shop_now.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {               

                 Fragment mFragment = new DetailFragment();
                 mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                 ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment);
                 ft.addToBackStack(null);
                 ft.commit();   


            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment);
         ft.addToBackStack(null);
         ft.commit();
```

Here  R.id.content_frame is not called from Parent Activity and if not try to change content_frame id in  parent activity , it might be duplicated .

Comment: check it in parent activity xml with content_frame i.e from where you are starting the main activity or you may not calling xml file in main activity .

Answer (score 0):

finaly i got solution,simple change tabhost setactivity from

```
tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.home_fragment);
```

to

```
tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getFragmentManager(), R.layout.home_fragment);
```